# Right way to implement encapsulation

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following Class scheme.

[image]

`National` have a `ArrayList` of `Zone`, `Zone` a `ArrayList` of `Region` and `Region` have a `ArrayList` of `Person`.

So i have the next questions:

1) Can i "push" a person trough national and zone to add it in Region?

for example:

```
National national = new National();
....
national.addPerson(person); // Every level has his own addPerson method
```

or

```
national.getZone(i).getRegion(i).addPerson(person);
```

What is the right way to do this in OOP?

2) Can a make a method where i return every person in a level?

I mean for example:

```
Zone zone = new Zone();
...
zone.getPersons(); //Return a ArrayList with the persons of every Region in Zone.
```

This goes against encapsulation?

3) A next(), hasNext(), first() methods for every level, so i can iterate in that particular level.

That's all. I get  encapsulation and OOP in general, but i can't figure out what is right to do, and what is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: **Stack Overflow** is not the place for this question. Search for a site suitable for this question on the [Stack Exchange Network](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik I believe this is on-topic.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik why is not place? Where else can i ask about encapsulation my sir?

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik You have not been on the site long enough to have a good feel for what is on-topic.  I suggest you refrain from making that judgement for a while.

Comment: @JimGarrison OK. Just thought that it's off-topic. I take my comment back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your class diagram, a `Person` must always be a member of a `Region`, that is, a `National` or `Zone` cannot directly contain `Person` objects that are not contained in a `Region` under it.

In that case the method matching signature `addPerson(Person p)` can occur only in `Region`.  As you indicated, then you would have to do

```
national.getZone(i).getRegion(j).addPerson(person);
```

There is no logical reason to have, say,

```
National#addPerson(Person p)
```

because `National` has no information on which `Zone` and `Region` the person belongs to.

However, you could add convenience methods to `National` and `Zone` to, as you call it, "push" a person down, but only if you provide the necessary data.

```
National#addPerson(ZoneId zid, RegionId rid, person) { ...
```

For `ZoneId` and `RegionId` substitute whatever key type you use to lookup the zone and region within a `National`.

```
Zone#AddPerson(RegionId rid, person) { ...
```

As above for `RegionId`.

This is just a start, you'll have to think through issues such as what happens when `ZoneId` and/or `RegionId` are not found on an `addPerson(...)` call.  In this design the only viable option is throwing an exception because you don't have enough information at that point to instantiate a `Zone` or `Region`.

EDIT:

If as you indicated in a comment, the `Person` object contains enough information to identify the `Zone` and `Region`, then your convenience methods in `National` and `Zone` can do the required lookup and delegate to the next `addPerson(Person p)` in the chain.

Comment: I miss one important thing, the Person class, have information about the Region and Zone where he belongs, in that case, National#addPerson(Person p), is valid? . Also can a Person be a member (as a Collection too) of Zone and National too? (so every person have to be added in National,Zone and Region) This break in anyway the OOP paradigm?

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Also, the other part of my post. A next method for every level in the chain is valid? or is have to be delegate for the class what actually have the Person class?.

Comment: A `getPersons()` method at every level should be fine, but it should return a new list and not a reference to the list being maintained internally.  It will _have_ to do this for the `National` and `Zone` levels since it has to combine multiple lists.  But even `Region` should not return a reference to its own list to prevent outside code from modifying it.  Rather than returning lists, however, you might investigate using custom iterators at each level to completely hide the list.

Comment: Ok, i implemented a custom iterator for each level and works great, Thanks you!